# Laravel cookie in serviceprovider not comparable

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I try to pass a variable based on a cookie value in my compose function to all my view to build my menu, with the use of serviceproviders [recommmended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5):

> File: Providers/ViewComposerServiceProvicer.php

```
public function boot(Request $request) { $this->composeTopBar($request);}

public function composeTopBar(Request $request)
{
     $cookieValue = $request->cookie('brand');
    // if value not set use default value.
    if($cookieValue == null)
    {
        $cookieValue = 1;
    }
    $brands = \App\Brand::orderBy('priority', 'asc')->get();
    foreach($brands as $brand){
        if($brand->id == $cookieValue){
            $brand->menuActive = true;
        }
        else{
            // show value to debug
            $brand->menuActive = $cookieValue;
        }
    }


    view()->composer('front.layouts.top', function ($view) use ($brands) {
        $view->with('brandItems',$brands );
    });
}
```

the cookieValue looks like

```
yJpdiI6IlNJODBvQ1RNM004OWVleyJpdiI6IlNJODBvQ1RNM004OWVleyJpdiI6IlNJODBvQ1RNM004OWVl
```

While the value in my controller looks like '`2`' How can i get the original value `2` in my compose function?

*I need to get the original value to compare it in my composeTopBar function so I can pass a variable to be true if it equals the cookie value.*

Method to set cookie

```
    $response = response()-> view('front.products.category', compact('products','category'));
    $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('brand',1));
    return $response;
```

Comment: Where have you defined this `composeTopBar()` method?

Comment: @MartinBean File: Providers/ViewComposerServiceProvicer.php ,      Boot function: public function boot(Request $request)
    {
        $this->composeTopBar($request);

Comment: How did you set that cookie? If you set it using any of Laravel's cookie-setting method, you shouldn't have a problem getting the decrypted cookie.

Comment: @SandyandiN.delaCruz i've added my method. i can view the value in my controllers though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a [class based composer](http://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers) .
The reason why this works is because it's called later in the lifecycle of laravel and the Cookie variables are decrypted. When using Closure based composers the values are encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: put the `view()` call as a parameter to `response()`.

```php
$response = response(view('front.products.category', compact('products','category')));
$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('brand', 1));
return $response;
```