# Laravel - passing cookie into service provider

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

Someone could explain me, how to use Cookie inside a service provider ( Module ).

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(public_path('themes/'.Cookie::get('name').'/views/modules/test'),'blog');
```

Currently the Cookie name looks like:

```
eyJpdiI6ImZxSk1uR2VMWlB4TDhJa0NPN29TdVE9PSIsI
```

... and much more

My job is to make multiple themes to each modules, but the problem is above.
Maybe there is another way to do that? I will be really grateful for help.

Comment: Laravel's cookies are encrypted, and the decryption process happens *after* the service providers are loaded, IIRC. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212802/laravel-cookie-in-serviceprovider-not-comparable

Comment: This post didn't explain me my next steps in creating this.