# Cookie::get() working in blade but not working in service provider laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

In a laravel 8 project, if I use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::get() in boot method of service provider, it is returning encrypted string. But when I use Cookie::get() in blade view file, it is returning decrypted value as expected.

##### AppServiceProvider.php

`dump(Cookie::get('app_language');      // returns "eyJpdiI6.....IifQ==" (encrypted value)`

##### login.blade.php

`dump(Cookie::get('app_language');      // returns "fr" (decrypted value)`

I need the decrypted value in service provider.

Answer (score 0):

The cookies are not decrypted before the service providers are ran, hence, you cannot do this without some custom code. This is why it does not work the way you wanted per default.

Give this a read, similar question with responses:
[Laravel cookie in serviceprovider not comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212802/laravel-cookie-in-serviceprovider-not-comparable)